# How to serve an api subdomain using apache, passenger, and rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger, subdomain

I created a subdomain like the following `myapp.example.com` and it works great ...has been.  Now I want to build an API using rails for the app (rails itself) so I created the subdomain `api.myapp.example.com`.  Currently the problem I'm getting is the api subdomain isn't getting routed to the rails app.

I tried adding the following to the apache conf file in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/example.com.conf`

`# example.com.conf
ServerAlias *.myapp.example.com`

I then restarted Apache, but still `api.myapp.example.com` wasn't being routed to rails application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ahhh, it ended being an easy fix

`# example.com.conf
ServerAlias myapp.example.com api.myapp.example.com`